# Drawing of "dotted" yz-plane in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw my first picture in tikz and I need a small help with the following. I want to draw a family of "surfaces" that consists of all the planes parallel to yz-plane, and all the individual points on the yz-plane. I drew the planes but am struggling with the points. So what I need is to fill the yz-plane with dots. Could you give me a help to fill this gap?

Below I put my code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);
\draw[line width=0.3mm,->] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$};     
\draw[line width=0.3mm,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) node[anchor=north east]{$z$};     
\draw[line width=0.3mm,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,7) node[anchor=east]{$x$};
\filldraw[color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.8] (0, 0, 2) -- (0, 3.5, 2) -- (2, 3.5, 2) --   (2, 0, 2) -- cycle;
\draw  (0, 0, 2) -- (0, 3.5, 2) -- (2, 3.5, 2) --   (2, 0, 2) -- cycle;
\filldraw[color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.8] (0, 0, 2.5) -- (0, 3.5, 2.5) -- (2, 3.5, 2.5) --   (2, 0, 2.5) -- cycle;
\draw  (0, 0, 2.5) -- (0, 3.5, 2.5) -- (2, 3.5, 2.5) --   (2, 0, 2.5) -- cycle;
\filldraw[color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.8] (0, 0, 3) -- (0, 3.5, 3) -- (2, 3.5, 3) --   (2, 0, 3) -- cycle;
\draw  (0, 0, 3) -- (0, 3.5, 3) -- (2, 3.5, 3) --   (2, 0, 3) -- cycle;
\filldraw[color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.8] (0, 0, 3.5) -- (0, 3.5, 3.5) -- (2, 3.5, 3.5) --   (2, 0, 3.5) -- cycle;
\draw  (0, 0, 3.5) -- (0, 3.5, 3.5) -- (2, 3.5, 3.5) --   (2, 0, 3.5) -- cycle;
\filldraw[color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.8] (0, 0, 4) -- (0, 3.5, 4) -- (2, 3.5, 4) --   (2, 0, 4) -- cycle;
\draw  (0, 0, 4) -- (0, 3.5, 4) -- (2, 3.5, 4) --   (2, 0, 4) -- cycle;
\filldraw[color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.8] (0, 0, 4.5) -- (0, 3.5, 4.5) -- (2, 3.5, 4.5) --   (2, 0, 4.5) -- cycle;
\draw  (0, 0, 4.5) -- (0, 3.5, 4.5) -- (2, 3.5, 4.5) --   (2, 0, 4.5) -- cycle;
\filldraw[color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.8] (0, 0, 5) -- (0, 3.5, 5) -- (2, 3.5, 5) --   (2, 0, 5) -- cycle;
\draw  (0, 0, 5) -- (0, 3.5, 5) -- (2, 3.5, 5) --   (2, 0, 5) -- cycle;
\filldraw[color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.8] (0, 0, 5.5) -- (0, 3.5, 5.5) -- (2, 3.5, 5.5) --   (2, 0, 5.5) -- cycle;
\draw  (0, 0, 5.5) -- (0, 3.5, 5.5) -- (2, 3.5, 5.5) --   (2, 0, 5.5) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: do you like to replace fill (`blue!...`) with pattern of dots? see `pattern library` on page 666 in tikz & pgf manual (V3.0.1.a)

Comment: @dexteritas Ups sorry I didn't think of that... I'll fix it :)

Comment: @Zarko No, I don't want to change my planes. They are exactly what I need. I want to fill only the plane x=0 with dots. So only the plane in the backround.

Comment: @T.P., than apply patter to this plane ... with something like `\fill[pattern=dots, pattern color=gray]  (0,0) ... ;`, in preamble you should add `\usetikzlibrary{patterns}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a command `\plane` for the redundancies to shorten the code and added a dotted plane at x=0, using the tikzlibrary `patterns` and the option `pattern=dots`.

Note: I use `\draw[fill=<color>]` to draw the black border and also the filling with one command.
Besides you can use `rectangle` to draw a rectangle between two points.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\plane}[2][fill=blue!10!white]{
    \draw[opacity=0.8,#1] (0, 0, #2) rectangle (2, 3.5, #2);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);
    \draw[line width=0.3mm,->] (O) --++ (4,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$};     
    \draw[line width=0.3mm,->] (O) --++ (0,4,0) node[anchor=north east]{$z$};     
    \draw[line width=0.3mm,->] (O) --++ (0,0,7) node[anchor=east]{$x$};

    \plane[draw=none,pattern=dots]{0};

    \foreach \x in {2,2.5,...,5.5}
        \plane{\x};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's exactly how I imagined my picture should be :D

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: Sure, I can click the checkmark. As for the upvoating, I tried but I can't do it, I think because of my low reputation. Step by step I learn how to use this site :D

Answer (score 0):

let me convert my comment to an answer ... some how similar to [dexteritas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/123129/dexteritas) answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% only for test
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[L/.append style={line width=0.3mm,->}]
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);
\draw[L] (O) --++ (4,0,0) node[below left] {$y$};
\draw[L] (O) --++ (0,4,0) node[below left] {$z$};
\draw[L] (O) --++ (0,0,7) node[left]       {$x$};
%
\fill[pattern=dots] (O) |- (2, 3.5, 0) |- cycle;
%
\foreach \x in {2,2.5,...,5.5}
    \draw[fill=blue!10!white,opacity=0.6] (0,0,\x) |- (2,3.5,\x) |- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @T.P., here is habit that thankfulness is expressed by voting of answer and accepting one, which solve your problem on the best way :)